# how to create a new boolean column that processes information from previous n rows

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe df, I would like to generate a new variable/column for each row based on the values in the previous n rows (for example previous 3).

For example, given the following:

INPUT

```
A   B  C
10  2  59.4
53  3  71.5
32  2  70.4
24  3  82.1
```

Calculation for D: if in the actual row in C or previous 3 rows in C there are 2 or more cells > 70 then 1, else 0

OUTPUT

```
A   B  C     D
10  2  59.4  0
53  3  71.5  0
32  2  70.4  1
24  3  82.1  1
```

How should I do it in pandas?

Comment: No, because in the 3rd row, you have the 71.5 and 70.4 that meet the conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @RafaelC's answer is the right approach.  I'm adding an answer to (a) provide better example data that covers edge cases and (b) to adjust @RafaelC's syntax slightly.  In particular:

- `min_periods = 1` allows for early rows whose index values are smaller than the window to be non-`NaN`
- `window = 4` allows for the current entry plus the previous 3 to be considered
- Use `sum()` instead of `size` to get only `True` values

Updated code:

```
window = 4
df.C.rolling(window, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x>70).sum()>=2)
```

Data:

```
A   B  C
10  2  59.4
53  3  71.5
32  2  70.4
24  3  82.1
11  4  10.1
10  5  1.0
12  3  2.3
13  2  1.1
99  9  70.2
12  9  80.0
```

Expected output according to OP rules:

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    1.0
6    0.0
7    0.0
8    0.0
9    1.0
Name: C, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, should use `rolling` and build your logic in the `apply`

```
window = 3
df.C.rolling(window).apply(lambda s: 1 if (s>=70).size >= 2 else 0)

0    NaN
1    NaN
2    1.0
3    1.0
```

You can also `fillna` to turn `NaN`s into `0`

```
.fillna(0)

0    0.0
1    0.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
```

Comment: Not sure this works if you add a few more example cases after OP's original data - try adding 4 more values to `C` that are less than 70.

Comment: How about `window=4;df.rolling(window, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x>70).sum()>=2)`?  That seems to handle edge cases correctly.